# How to disable the Quit func under the mutilDocument environment?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I haove a mutilDocument App , I found that when I open a window with the method :

```
[NSApp beginSheet: [MultiWin window] modalForWindow: mainWindows modalDelegate: nil didEndSelector: nil  contextInfo: nil];
```

The Quit func in mainmeny already highlight , this can confuse the user that the Quit app func can work under this vironment.I want to disable the Quit func under that , how to do? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should implement validateMenuItem: in your window controller class.  Check out the [NSMenuValidation Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add an outlet for the menu item, connect it in IB, then set its `enabled` to `NO` after you begin your sheet and back to `YES` in your sheet-ended callback.